# Share Files over the Network - What packages?

Tags: networking, apache2, samba, sharing

I see a pop up that says

> #### Share Files over the Network
>
> *This feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system*

Simple enough, but what packages do I need?

Comment: I have samba installed and am still getting the message above

Answer (score 9):

what worked for me was install Apache2. Just install a LAMP server (or just apache) --

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then it should work just fine.

---

In 16.04 the change is from

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: He is not trying to share it via HTTP. He is trying to share it like in windows. In this case the answer by jrg is the correct one.

Comment: Apparently apache2 is required for the Ubuntu's file sharing feature to work.

Comment: Using 16.04 here. I have first installed samba (and dependencies using synaptic) to no effect. I then apache2, again delegating to synaptic; it then activated the network activities. I have edited the post above to display the change in the Personal File Sharing Preference dialogue window (pending moderator's approval)

Answer (score 4):

When you share files over the network in Ubuntu, you use `samba` - so you'll need to run `sudo apt-get install samba` and then try sharing the folder again.

Comment: Not necessarily...I'd suggest `NFS` for a pure Linux environment. Though, AFAIK Samba is default choice of Ubuntu.

Comment: Personally I would also install smbfs and system-config-samba packages the first makes it possible to create permanent mounts through fstab and the last is an admin config app for your own shares which will make it easier to setup and modify your own shares plus my own shares wouldn't show up on a vista machine until I had shared them using the Samba config.

Comment: @Allan True. 

@Bobby Yeah. Samba isn't necessarily the *best* way to do this, but it's the *default* choice.