# Cannot upload photos from mobile with bluetooth in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, phone

I can download photos with bluetooth from my Ubuntu 15.04 computer to my Nokia 302 mobile phone. But I cannot upload photos from this same mobile to this same computer with bluetooth.

Neither I could not get nokuntu programm (nokinux-0.0.8.6.tar.gz) working in my 15.04 computer (to be used instead of Nokia Suite, which is made to work in Microsoft computers).

What could I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Search Dash for "Personal File Sharing" and click on the result and you should see this
[image]

Then make sure the box next to "Receive files in Downloads folder over Bluetooth" has a checkmark in it and it should work

Comment: Jeremy31 hi, Thank you very much for your precise reply !! But, from where and how to get (download)  the necessary program packages of this service / application  for 15.04. ? Brgs, Kauko Peltonen

Comment: It is part of the ISO download so you shouldn't have to download anything unless you aren't using the Unity desktop

Comment: Jeremy hi,  Thank you for your kind reply and advice. When I open  ''Personal File Sharing'' from Unity, the same ''Preferences'' page (which you displayed in your original answer) opens. This page says, that ''This function cannot be utilized, because necessary program packages have not been installed to this computer'' (this is my translation from Finnish, sorry for possible misstakes).  Only 'Manual' and 'Shut' are possible here.

That is why I ask where and how to get (download) the necessary program packages of this service / application for 15.04. ?
Brgds, Kauko Peltonen

Comment: JEREMY HI ! I OPENED IN UNITY THE SAME 'PERSONAL SHARE FILES' INPUT PAGE ONCE MORE AND CLICKED MY INPUTS TO IT AS YOUR ADVICED IN YOUR ORIGINAL ANSWER. THEN I JUST CLOSED THE PAGE, OPENED THE BLUETOOTH TO MY MOBILE AND ... UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY PHOTOS FROM MY MOBILE TO MY 15.04 COMPUTER. NOW IT WORKS OK AND WELL !!! WARM THANKS TO YOU ONCE MORE !!! BRGDS, KAUKO PELTONEN

Comment: Jeremy31 or some other: Could you please ask/advice those, who make / update Ubuntu Bluetooth intructions, to add this veryu usefull ''Personal File Sharing Preferences'' instruction directly to Ubuntu Bluetooth  user instructions or Ubuntu Bluetooth opening page ?

Comment: As you've probably figured out by now, that's a red herring. It's saying that network file sharing can't be enabled. These instructions will probably correct the issue (but I haven't needed to try them.) https://askubuntu.com/a/24364