# Send files from Android to Ubuntu via bluetooth fails 'transfer forbidden by target device'

Tags: bluetooth

My Ubuntu system is 16.04, running on an Alienware 15. 
And bluetooth software is [blueman-applet v2.0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd7Tk.png)

Hardware info

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
```

Here is an extract from the syslog

```
Sep  6 15:16:43 vimos-Alienware-15 bluetoothd[1109]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 20:A6:80:FC:1E:AA: Protocol not available
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: CONNECT(0x0), (null)(0xffffffff)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: CONNECT(0x0), (null)(0x0)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: PUT(0x2), (null)(0xffffffff)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 gnome-session[3509]: (blueman-applet:3756): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: open(/home/vimos/.cache/obexd/IMG_20170825_171735.jpg): Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: PUT(0x2), FORBIDDEN(0x43)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: DISCONNECT(0x1), (null)(0xffffffff)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: DISCONNECT(0x1), SUCCESS(0x20)
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 obexd[3940]: disconnected: Transport got disconnected
Sep  6 15:16:54 vimos-Alienware-15 bluetoothd[1109]: Unable to get io data for Object Push: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

And my personal file sharing config is like this:

[image: personal sharing]

Comment: Did you enable receive files over bluetooth in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot upload photos from mobile with bluetooth in 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647789/cannot-upload-photos-from-mobile-with-bluetooth-in-15-04)

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you! I guess I have the same config as in the post refered here. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

In case you were using Gnome, please note that the Bluetooth receiving works only when the bluetooth tab of the `gnome-control-center` is opened.

[Ref.](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/sharing-bluetooth.html.en):

> Bluetooth-enabled devices can send files to your Downloads folder only
> when the Bluetooth panel is open.

Comment: For me (Ubuntu 18.04) this still is not enough. When I exchange files between smartphones, I get a notification and the choice to accept or decline. I don't get that choice between ubuntu box and smartphone, neither way. I did upload a new wallpaper to a smartphone, but cannot figure aut what is different this tine.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the Obexd deamon with the `-a` option like:

```
/usr/libexec/bluetooth/obexd -a
```