# Personal File Sharing, "packages are not installed"

Tags: bluetooth, sharing

In Personal File Sharing menu I am getting this. I want to enable this. Here, what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to share files from network, or do you only want to share files via Bluetooth?

Comment: At this moment just Bluetooth is necessary.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as I cannot reproduce this problem in Ubuntu 20.04. l have file sharing enabled and Apache 2 is not installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share Files over the Network - What packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24346/share-files-over-the-network-what-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Install the following

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd
```

and restart Personal File Sharing and enable sharing over the network.

Then, to share a folder, right-click and choose properties. Then use the `Local Network Share` tab to share it.

[image]

You should now be able to browse your network using Nautilus and mount this folder from other Ubuntu machines, but not from Windows machines.

*I tested this on Ubuntu 17.04*

Answer (score 0):

Use

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

This solution has been provided from [Share Files over the Network - What packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24346/share-files-over-the-network-what-packages)

I got the same issue on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I fixed it